# Unable to play youtube video in window 8.1 winjs library

Tags: youtube-api, winjs, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to play youtube video in my window 8.1 app, with the following code.

```
     var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
     var content = '<iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
     WinJS.Utilities.setInnerHTMLUnsafe(videoPlayer, content);
```

where the videoplayer is name of div where video player appears, but I am not able to play the video. 
I have also tried using sample code from 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples
but it didn't work as well. So please can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this scenario to work for me, but I had to jump through some hoops to make it work.

First, in order to load the external script they need to communicate with the iframe, I had to sandbox the player in its own outer iframe that could run in the web context:

```
<div class="playerContainer">
    <iframe class="playerFrame" src="ms-appx-web:///pages/video/iframe.html" style="visibility: hidden" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then I had to edit my APPXMANIFEST to include the YouTube domain as a ContentURI rule:

```
https://*.youtube.com
```

My iframe.html was pretty simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Player Iframe</title>
    <link href="/pages/video/iframe.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/pages/video/iframe.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="player"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1"
            frameborder="0"
            style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Then inside of iframe.js I borrowed heavily from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        if (e.data.op === 'load') {
            loadVideo(e.data.args)
        } else if (e.data.op === 'resize') {
            resize(e.data.args);
        } else if (e.data.op === 'destroy') {
            destroy();
        }
    });


    var player;
    var videoId;

    function loadVideo(args) {

        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var playerEl = document.getElementById('player');
        playerEl.height = window.innerHeight;
        playerEl.width = window.innerWidth;


        videoId = args.videoId;

        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            playerEl.style.visibility = 'visible';
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function resize(args) {
        player && player.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    function destroy() {
        player && player.destroy();
        player = null;
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.loadVideoById(videoId);
    }

})();
```

As you can see from the above, I am using iframe's postMessage to tell the wrapping iframe to load the videoId that I want:

```
iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
    iframe.style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (iframe.contentWindow) {
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({ op: "load", args: { videoId: video.id} }, "*");
    }
});
```

Hope that helps some. The YouTube IFrame API is pretty finicky and didn't work right for me when loaded any other way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am facing the same problem, there is not display at all. I would like to know is there any api which help me to play youtube video in MediaPlayer framework.

Comment: Sorry to hear it's not displaying for you. Are you getting any errors in the JS console?

Also, YouTube is never going to let you get the raw video stream, so I don't think you can use the Player Framework.

Comment: I get the error. `Can’t load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID '{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}'.  Apps can't load ActiveX controls.`